# UnicodeDecodeError: invalid continuation byte when trying to read in document

Tags: file, unicode, decode, traceback

I am trying to read in a document containing product data and print certain product's data out.  Problem is, I can't seem to get it read in without error.  I am just trying to print the first 100 characters just to get it read in so I can then figure out what specifically I need to print and how to pull it out of the file.  But I am stuck reading it in.  The document is in UTF-8, or it should be... what am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
products = open('products.csv')
productsread = products.read()
print(productsread[:100])
```

And here is the Traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nilescratchpad.py", line 2, in <module>
productsread = products.read()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 7451: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: If you read the document and it throws an error with the UTF-8 codec, then it isn't UTF-8, or at least has errors in it.  You could try `open('products.csv',errors='replace')`.

Comment: There must have been an error in it somewhere.  That worked!!!  Thanks so much!  Just out of curiosity, what is it replacing the error with?

Answer (score 6):

If you read the document and it throws an error with the UTF-8 codec, then it isn't UTF-8, or at least has errors in it. `open('products.csv',encoding='utf8',errors='replace')` will replace all errors with the Unicode codepoint `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, but make sure most of your document actually **is** UTF-8.

Comment: This works!  Thanks so much!  It must have had an error in it somewhere... because most of the document is UTF-8 and what it displays now makes sense and is correct after taking your suggestion.  Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Got it!  Will do now!  I am new to Stack Overflow, and Python, and coding... so I've gotta get to a 15 reputation until my votes show up, or so it says.